# Is there a simple proof for $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{2x^2\log^2 x}{(x^2-1)^2}dx=\frac{1}{4}(7\zeta(3)+\pi^2)$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

This morning I've computed easy computations with simple integral representations for **Apéry constant** and I find a (conjecture) formula using an online integrator (**Wolfram Alpha**), I woluld like if it is possible find a proof of such fact, since I believe that it could be easy, since this online tool know how compute.

> **Question.** Can you give a proof of 
>   $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{2x^2\log^2 x}{(x^2-1)^2}dx=\frac{1}{4}(7\zeta(3)+\pi^2)?$$
>   Please, if you known yet the result reference the work, and of course if you believe that it is false say me. **Thanks in advance.**

Early, I will choose the more simple proof of this fact.

**My context:** I don't know if it was in the literature or if there are mistakes. Feel free to add useful comments if you find mistakes. This morning I was reading the section about simple integral representations for **Apéry constant**, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant). We can compute easily that 
$$\zeta(3)=\frac{4}{7}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\log^2 x}{x^2-1}dx,$$
after, if there are no mistakes this gives, using integration by parts $u=\frac{\log x}{x^2-1}$, and $dv=\log x dx$, 
$$\frac{4}{7}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{-x^2+1+3x^2\log x-\log x-2x^2\log^2 x}{(x^2-1)^2}dx\right)$$

Comment: Previous **Question** is a conjecture: I don't know how prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it is the most simple way, but it works. Let $x=1/t
 $. We get $$I=-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^{2}\left(t\right)}{\left(1-t^{2}\right)^{2}}dt=2\sum_{k\geq0}\left(k+1\right)\int_{0}^{1}t^{2k}\log^{2}\left(t\right)dt
 $$ and now integrating by parts twice we have $$\int_{0}^{1}t^{2k}\log^{2}\left(t\right)dt=-\frac{2}{2k+1}\int_{0}^{1}t^{2k}\log\left(t\right)dt=\frac{2}{\left(2k+1\right)^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}t^{2k}dt=\frac{2}{\left(2k+1\right)^{3}}
 $$ so $$I=4\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{k+1}{\left(2k+1\right)^{3}}=4\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{k}{\left(2k-1\right)^{3}}
 $$ now observe that $$4\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{k}{\left(2k-1\right)^{3}}=2\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{\left(2k-1\right)^{2}}+2\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{\left(2k-1\right)^{3}}
 $$ and, due to the absolute convergence, we have $$\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{\left(2k-1\right)^{2}}=\zeta\left(2\right)-\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{4k^{2}}=\frac{3}{4}\zeta\left(2\right)=\frac{\pi^{2}}{8}
 $$ and $$\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{\left(2k-1\right)^{3}}=\zeta\left(3\right)-\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{8k^{3}}=\frac{7}{8}\zeta\left(3\right)
 $$ hence $$I=\frac{1}{4}\left(7\zeta\left(3\right)+\pi^{2}\right).
 $$

Comment: Very thanks much, it very simple and nice.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with an integration by parts with $v=x\log^2(x)$ and $u'=\frac{2x}{(x^2-1)^2}$ . We get (the boundary term vansihs)

$$
I=\int_1^{\infty}dx\frac{\log(x)^2}{x^2-1}+2\int_1^{\infty}dx\frac{\log(x)}{x^2-1}
$$

using your previous result we get

$$
I=\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)+2\int_1^{\infty}dx\frac{\log(x)}{x^2-1}
$$

The last integral can be caluclated by for example expanding the denominator as a geometric series (after performing an transforamtion $x\rightarrow 1/x$) resulting in a sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$ which is easily shown to be $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$. Therefore

$$
I=\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^2}{4}
$$

Comment: Very thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify to known integrals

\begin{align}
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{2x^2\log^2 x}{(x^2-1)^2}dx
& \overset{x\to\frac1x} = \int_0^{1}\frac{2\log^2 x}{(1-x^2)^2}dx 
= \int_0^{1}\frac{\log^2 x}x d\left( \frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\right)\\
& \overset{IBP}=\int_0^{1}\frac{\log^2 x}{1-x^2}dx-2\int_0^{1}\frac{\log x}{1-x^2}dx \\
&=\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)-2\cdot(-\frac{\pi^2}8)= \frac14[7\zeta(3)+\pi^2]
\end{align}

where $\int_0^{1}\frac{\log^2 x}{1-x^2}dx\overset{x\to\frac1x}=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\log^2 x}{x^2-1}dx =\frac74\zeta(3)$ and [$\int_0^{1}\frac{\log x}{1-x^2}dx =-\frac{\pi^2}8$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913260/find-integral-int-01-frac-ln-x1-x2-mathrmdx)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{1}^{\infty}{2x^{2}\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over
\pars{x^{2} - 1}^{2}}\,\dd x}
\,\,\,\stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ 1/x}{=}\,\,\,
2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over \pars{1 - x^{2}}^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\left. -\,{1 \over a}\,\partiald{}{a}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over
a^{2} - x^{2}}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ a\ = 1}
=
\left. -\,\partiald{}{a}\pars{{1 \over a}\int_{0}^{1/a}{\ln^{2}\pars{ax} \over
1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x}\,\right\vert_{\ a\ = 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\color{red}{\mrm{f}\pars{1} - \mrm{f}\, '\pars{1}}
\\[2mm] &\
\mbox{where}\quad 
\mrm{f}\pars{a} \equiv
\int_{0}^{1/a}{\ln^{2}\pars{ax} \over 1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{a} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{1/a}{\ln^{2}\pars{ax} \over 1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1/a}{\ln^{2}\pars{ax} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{-1/a}{\ln^{2}\pars{-ax} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
-\int_{0}^{1/a}\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\ln\pars{ax}\,\dd x
\\[2mm] &\
+ \int_{0}^{-1/a}\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\ln\pars{-ax}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1/a}\mrm{Li}_{3}'\pars{x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{-1/a}\mrm{Li}_{3}'\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 \over a} - \mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{-\,{1 \over a}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{1}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1} - \mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{-1}}
\\ && \ds{=
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{3}} -
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n^{3}}}
\\ & \ds{=} &
\ds{{7 \over 4}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{3}} =
\color{red}{{7 \over 4}\,\zeta\pars{3}}}
\\[5mm]
\ds{\mrm{f}\, '\pars{1}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1} + \mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{-1}
\\ \ds{=}
-\,{\pi^{2} \over 6} + \pars{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 12}} =
\color{red}{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 4}}}
\end{array}\right. \label{2}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
With (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}):
$$
\bbx{\large\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{1}^{\infty}{2x^{2}\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over
\pars{x^{2} - 1}^{2}}\,\dd x} =
{1 \over 4}\bracks{7\zeta\pars{3} + \pi^{2}}} \\
$$