# Calculating integrals using power series and uniform convergence

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I would like to find $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{1-x^2} dx$$ using power series approach by first finding the power series of $$\frac{\ln x}{1-x^2} $$ and then showing that it is uniformly convergent and thus we can interchange summation and integration. So the integral is equal to $$-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} $$May I ask how can I approach the question? I could find the power series expansion but upon integration, it does not seem to get me anywhere near the form that I would like to get...

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913260/find-integral-int-01-frac-ln-x1-x2-mathrmdx?

Comment: Hint:- Note
$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{1}{2k+1}=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{2k}$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already proved that,
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{1-x^{2}} dx=-\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2}}$$
To evaluate just note that,
$$-\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2}}=-\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{k^{2}} +\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{4k^2}$$
So it's the series of zeta function i.e $\zeta(s)$ evaluated at $s=2$ which was proved to be $\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$.
So the required sum will evaluate to,
$$-\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}+\frac{\pi^{2}}{24}$$.