# Is there any other simple method to evaluate $\int_0^{1} \frac{\ln ^n x}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, riemann-zeta

After reading the fantastic solutions to the integral in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1913260/732917),

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1 - x^2} \mathrm{d}x=-\frac{\pi^2}8,$$
and found that $$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^2 x}{1-x^2} d x =\frac{7\zeta(3)}{4}.  $$

Then I keep on exploring the integral in general and obtain a formula,

> $$
> \int_0^{1} \frac{\ln ^n x}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}dx= \frac{(-1)^n n !}{2}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\zeta(n)+\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right) \zeta(n+1)\right]
> $$
> where $n\ge 2.$

First of all, we use its partner integral
$$
I(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^a}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2} d x
$$
Using the series for $|x|<1,$
$$
\frac{1}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k x^{2 k-2},
$$
we have $$
I(a) =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \int_0^1 x^{2 k-2+a} d x =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{2 k-1+a}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^n x}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2} d x & =\left.\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\partial^n}{d a^n}\left(\frac{k}{2 k-1+a}\right)\right|_{a=0} \\
& =(-1)^n n ! \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{(2 k-1)^{n+1}} \\
& =\frac{(-1)^n n !}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{(2 k-1)^n}+\frac{1}{(2 k-1)^{n+1}}\right] \\
& =\boxed{\frac{(-1)^n n !}{2}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\zeta(n)+\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right) \zeta(n+1)\right]}
\end{aligned}
$$
For examples,
$$
I_2=\frac{3}{4} \zeta(2)+\frac{7}{8} \zeta(3)= \frac{\pi^2}{8} +\frac{7}{8} \zeta(3)
$$
$$
I_3=-3\left[\frac{7}{8} \zeta(3)+\frac{15}{16} \zeta(4)\right]=-\frac{21}{8} \zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{32}
$$

**My question:** Is there any other simple method to evaluate $\int_0^{1} \frac{\ln ^n x}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}dx $?

Comment: I don't think you can do much since there is no known simple closed form for $\zeta(n)$ when $n$ is odd and is greater than $1$.

Comment: Can we evaluate the integral when $n\ge 2$ is a real number ?

Comment: The case $n=2$ is $\frac18\pi^2+\frac78\zeta(3)$. You can't get simpler than that.

Comment: @Lai $\log x$ is negative for $0<x<1$. What do you mean by its power $n$ when $n$ is not an integer?

Comment: Yes, so $n$ must be an integer greater than or equal to 2.  Is there any other method?

Comment: I do not know the answer but I admire. It is a very nice work.

Comment: Thank you for all your support.  I just wonder if there are some other methods with answers in other form, then we may simplify it.

Comment: You almost have $\eta(x)=(1-2^{1-x})\zeta(x)$ with the [Dirichlet eta](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=functionexpand%5BDirichleteta%28x%29%5D) function

Comment: Why downvotes for this question ? Nice work, good explanation, good presentatio from an obviously enthusiastic user.

Comment: I do want to know. Please give reasons for me to improve!

Comment: @Lai Don't let it bother you. Your posts are always very interesting.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I better rewrite the question as :Is there any other simple method to evaluate $\int_0^{1} \frac{\ln ^n x}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}dx $?

Comment: Martin, thank you for your support and encouragement.  I’ll continue to write post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize
\begin{align}
J(m)=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^m x}{1-x^2}dx 
=&\int_0^1  \frac{\ln^m x }{1-x}dx -\int_0^1 {\frac{x\ln^m x }{1-x^2} } \overset{x^2\to x}{dx} \\=& \ \left(1-\frac1{2^{m+1}}\right)\int_0^1\frac{\ln^mx}{1-x}dx\\
=&\  \left(1-\frac1{2^{m+1}}\right)(-1)^m m!\ \zeta(m+1)
\end{align}
to evaluate
\begin{align}
\int_0^{1} \frac{\ln^n x}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}dx
&=\int_0^{1} \frac{\ln ^n x}{2x}\ d\left(\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\right)
\overset{ibp}=\frac12J(n)
-\frac n2 J(n-1)\\
&= \frac{(-1)^n n !}{2}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\zeta(n)+\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right) \zeta(n+1)\right]
\end{align}

Comment: Wow, a decent solutions with a unique skill!