Show that $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1 - x^2 y^2} \, dx \, dy = \frac{\pi^2}{8}$
I'm trying to simply prove the Basel Series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{16} + \dots = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$
by deconstructing it into a sum of Sub-Series.
I was able to show using WolframAlpha that
$$
\frac{1}{(2n - 1)^2} = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} x^{2n-2} y^{2n-2} \, dx \, dy
$$
Thus,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n - 1)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} x^{2n-2} y^{2n-2} \, dx \, dy = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1 - x^2 y^2} \, dx \, dy 
$$
But, to complete the Basel proof and avoid any circular arguments, I need to show that
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1 - x^2 y^2} \, dx \, dy  = \frac{\pi^2}{8} \tag{1}
$$
Proof
Every natural number $n$ can be written in one and only one way as $2^mq$ where $q=(2n-1)$ is an odd number.
Define the Sub-Series:
$$
S_m = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(2^m (2n - 1)\right)^2} = \frac{1}{4^m} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n - 1)^2}
$$
Notice the sum of all $S_m$ reconstructs the Basel series:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} S_m = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^m} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n - 1)^2} = \frac{4}{3} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n - 1)^2}
$$
The result follows from $(1)$:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{4}{3} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n - 1)^2} = \frac{4}{3} \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{8} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \quad \blacksquare
$$

I saw an article once that evaluates the integral of $\frac{1}{1-x^2 y^2}$ with the substitution $x = \frac{\sin u}{\cos v}, y = \frac{\sin v}{\cos u}$.  (I have no idea how they came up with that substitution, though, and it seems miraculous the way things work out.)

I'm curious if that integral introduces a circular argument by using the known Basel series result? Thanks.

The non-circular strategy is to evaluate the integral without using the Basel result, then write it as a multiple of $\zeta(2)$ to solve the Basel problem. @DanielSchepler's comment gives the approach you want. You'll get $\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2-v}\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$.

I think the article was a survey of ways to prove $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.  If I remember correctly, one of the other alternatives was the common proof involving finding the Fourier series for (the periodic extension of) $f(x) = x$ then applying Parseval's identity.  Yet another was to write a polynomial with $\cot(k\pi/(2n+1)), k=1, \ldots, n$ as roots, then use a Vieta type identity to find $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \cot^2(k\pi/(2n+1))$, then use the bounds $\cot \theta < \theta < \csc \theta$ for $\theta\in (0, \pi/2)$ to give a Squeeze Theorem argument.

@DanielSchepler I hope you can dig up a link to that article, although there will be an MSE question of similar content. That squared cotangent one is my favourite actually, if we exclude simultaneous treatments of all the even zeta constants.

See Proof 2 here. @DanielSchepler Are you thinking of the linked article?

You might also like looking at links in the comments and the answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884418/how-to-evaluate-int-01-int-01-frac11-xy-dy-dx-to-prove-sum-n/1885211#1885211

\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} &\frac{1}{1 - x^2 y^2} dy \, dx   
=\int_0^1 \frac{\tanh^{-1}x}{x}dx\\
=& \int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{2t}{(1+x)^2-4xt^2}dt\ dx
= \int_0^1 \frac{\sin^{-1}t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt= \frac{\pi^2}{8}
\end{align}

Nice! Just to clarify your proof, it's non-circular to deduce $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1 - x^2 y^2} , dx , dy  = \frac{\pi^2}{8} \tag{1}$$ I'm always fearful of Basel $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ insidiously inserting itself into proofs. Thanks.

@vengy There is no circularity. The double integral is evaluated elementarily..

Completed the Basel Proof using your solution.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-x^2 y^2} d x d y 
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{1+x y}+\frac{1}{1-x y}\right) d x d y \\
& =\frac{1}{2}  \int_0^1\left[\frac{\ln (1+x y)}{y}-\frac{\ln (1-x y)}{y}\right]_0^1 \\
& = \frac{1}{2}  \int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right)}{y} d y \\& =- \int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2} d t, \quad \textrm{ where }t=\frac{1-y}{1+y}.  \\
& =- \left(-\frac{\pi^2}{8} \right)\\
& =\frac{\pi^2}{8}
\end{aligned}
$$
where the second last answer comes from my post or post without the use  of the formula $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

wendy, you are right! I fixed it.

Excuse me for so many careless mistakes. I am sorry.

Could you explain how you obtain
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2} \mathrm dt =-\frac{\pi^2}{8},$$
please?

@vengy : The proof in the link you provide does indeed depend on the Basel result; so it is of no use in the present context. Anyway, my question was addressed to Lai, who (I hope) will be able to provide a direct proof.

John, may the link below answer your question?https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3805433/732917

One more link  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4994478/732917 from my post  may help .

John, thank you for your good question by which I had just updated my post.

The proof in the first (2020) link you gave does the job well. I edited the layout for legibility. (Your new, alternative, proof is good too; but I prefer the earlier one as it doesn't need so many square roots.)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
